# Counting how many factors an integer has

Tags: python, factors

So I have written a function to determine how many factors a number has and list that number. However my function is not outputting the correct information.

```
def num_factors(integer):
    result = 0
    for i in range(1,integer+1):
        if integer%i == 0:
            result +=1
    return result

print(num_factors(5))
print(num_factors(6))
print(num_factors(97))
print(num_factors(105))
print(num_factors(999))
```

For some reason it is outputting:

```
2
4
2
8
8
```

when it should be outputting:

```
0
2
0
6
6
```

Comment: Your loop doesn't need to go all the way up to `integer` to find all the factors, but just up to its square root `math.floor(integer**0.5)`. But you need to change a little your algorithm

Comment: Also it is correct. Prime numbers are defined by having exactly 2 dividers

Comment: You are also test for `integer / 1` which will always be true

Comment: 5 is, in fact, evenly divisible by 1 and 5.  Why do you say that the answer 2 is wrong?

Comment: It’s returning the correct output. If you don’t want to include 1 and the number itself as factors, loop from 2 to integer.

Comment: I should have been more specific, I completely forgot to mention I was supposed to leave out 1, and the integer in question. Thank you for your help, I can't believe I missed that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the line `for i in range(1,integer+1):` you are looping through all the numbers between 1 and your integer, including 1 and your integer, which are of course factors.

So for example if `integer = 5`, you'd loop over 1, 2, 3, 4, and 5. Out of these 1 and 5 are both of course factors of 5.

You could edit the line to `for i in range(2,integer):` to fix the error. The resulting code would look like this:

```py
def num_factors(integer):
    result = 0
    for i in range(2,integer):
        if integer%i == 0:
            result +=1
    return result

print(num_factors(5))
print(num_factors(6))
print(num_factors(97))
print(num_factors(105))
print(num_factors(999))
```

Though as someone in the comments suggested, you could reduce the search space even more.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you are counting division by 1 and the test integer itself.

You either need to subtract 2 or skip `1` and `integer` to get what you want as the desired output:

```
def num_factors(integer):
    result = 0
    for i in range(2,integer): # skips 1 and integer...
        if integer%i == 0:
            result +=1
    return result
```

And *even better* is to realize that for every `x * y` that is a factor of `integer` we only need to find one of them (ie, `16` has `2`,`4`,and `8` as factors. Count 2 twice (2 x 8=16) and 4 once (4 x 4=16))   And since one will be less than or equal to the square root of `integer` just loop to the square root of `integer` and increment by 2 instead of by 1 and only make a fraction of the tests (and make the result 1000's of times faster):

```
def num_factors(integer):
    result = 0
    stop=int(float(integer)**0.5)
    for i in range(2,stop+1):
        if integer%i == 0:
            result +=2
    if stop*stop==integer: result-=1    
    return result

for x in (5,6,97,105,999):
    print(f'{x}: {num_factors(x)}')
```

Prints:

```
5: 0
6: 2
97: 0
105: 6
999: 6
```

---

BTW: It is, in fact, [customary](https://www.basic-mathematics.com/counting-factors.html) to count `1` and the integer itself as factors. So all these results *should* be +2 and your original solution was actually correct. To make the solutions above correct, just start with `result=2`

Answer (score 1):

sympy provides this function to find prime factors.

```
>>> from sympy.ntheory import factorint
>>> factorint(6008)   # 6008 = (2**3) * (751**1)
{2: 3, 751: 1}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
num_factors=lambda integer : len([e  for e in range(1,integer) if integer%e==0 and e not in [1,integer]])



print(num_factors(5))
print(num_factors(6))
print(num_factors(97))
print(num_factors(105))
print(num_factors(999))
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it this way:

```
def num_factors(integer):
    for i in range(1, integer, 1):
        if integer % i == 0:
            print(i)

print(num_factors(5))
print(num_factors(6))
print(num_factors(97))
print(num_factors(105))
print(num_factors(999))
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, it's not really the question you're asking right now, but it may be your next question.  Your algorithm works fine if your integer is small, but what about when your integer is large?  Suppose `integer = 1_200_000_000`?

You need to find the prime factorization of the integer:

```
integer = p1**q1 * p2**q2 * p3**q3 * .....
```

and the number of factors (including 1 and the integer itself) is

```
(q1 + 1)(q2 + 1)(q3 + 1)....
```

Since `1,200,000,000 = (2**10)(3**1)(5**8)`, the number of factors is `(11 * 2 * 8) = 176.`